# Fontspec doesn't find Tex Gyre Pagella Italic

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm using XeLaTeX and when calling

```
\newfontfamily\headingfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Italic}
```

I get the message

```
Requested font "TeX Gyre Pagella Italic" at 11.99997pt -> font not found, using "nullfont" 
! Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Pagella Italic" cannot be found.
```

I can see that Windows 10 lists the font as installed, I have the current versions of packages fontspec, libertine, and I refreshed the font map with the MikTeX Console, but it still seems to not be able to find the font.

Below is MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Italic}
\begin{document}
XX
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pagella family uses "TeX Gyre Pagella" as family name. The italic shape is called "TeXGyrePagella-Italic". In addition, you are not setting a font family but a single font, so it makes more sense to use `\newfontface`. Overall, the following works for me using TeXLive 2019 on Debian Linux:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\newfontface\headingfont{TeXGyrePagella-Italic}
\begin{document}
\headingfont XX
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `xelatex` dosen't find the font by name. To fix that, you have to specify the font file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{texgyrepagella-italic.otf}
\begin{document}
  \headingfont XX 
\end{document}
```

If you run `pdffonts` you can see, that the right font is used:

```
name                                     type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
---------------------------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SLTSXB+TeXGyrePagella-Italic-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
LJPSEU+LinLibertineO-Identity-H          CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
\newfontface\headingfont{TeXGyrePagella-Italic}
```

or

```
\newfontfamily\headingfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}\textit{...}
```